# Impala and Kudu without HDFS

Tags: hdfs, impala, kudu

When I start impala, it says the following error:

> "Currently configured default filesystem: ProxyLocalFileSystem. fs.defaultFS (file:///) is not supported"

In configs I have said to use local disk but it searches for HDFS, doesn't write any files to it, but just want it to be installed and running, then I don't get this error.

I have tried changing the location to local disk but it wants HDFS to be running in the background.

Can Impala and Kudu work without HDFS?

Is it needed for something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can run impala without HDFS.

1st change the default file system to (file://) from hdfs, this can be done by editing the core-site.xml  "fs.defaultFS" property and make sure it is properly linked to impala.(using the right core-site.xml)  then add the "-abort_on_config_error=false" in your arguments for impala daemon or add this to your /etc/default/impala  file.

This will cause the error to be printed but will not cause an abort of impala daemon.
Credit to Tim Armstrong

[More Referance](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cm_props_cdh540_impala.html)